# How to send element's :visibile state to localStorage after a jQuery slideToggle() event

Tags: jquery, local-storage, slidetoggle

I have a div structure in which I'm calling slideToggle on the overall wrapper div in order to expand/collapse the contents of the div.

I would like to store the state of the div (open or closed) depending on the state the user leaves the div.

In the code below, regardless of the expand/collapse of the div group, the console's alert(localStorage.getItem('widgetPreview')) always returns visible:

```
$('#myDiv').on('click',function(){
    $(this).children().slideToggle();
    if((this).children().is(':visible')){
        localStorage.setItem('widgetPreview','visible');
    }
    else
    {
        localStorage.setItem('widgetPreview','hidden');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myDiv').on('click',function(){
    $(this).children().slideToggle().promise().done(function() {
        var vis = $(this).is(':visible') ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        localStorage.setItem('widgetPreview', vis);
    });
});
```

Comment: The only downside is the callback will be triggered once for each of `$(this).children()`, you can get a single callback with `.promise().done(handleit)`. Won't be an issue if there is only one child

Comment: @KevinB - good eye, changed it. It would work the same, but there's no need to store the same value over and over for each element etc.

Comment: When I changed the function to add promise().done(handleit) it no longer stores the hidden value. Its always visible.

Comment: @ScottBlanchard - Not sure what you mean, I already added a promise and removed the original callback method?